# Find the end-of-month date from any date entered in MS Excel

Tags: excel, date

I need to take the date from one cell, find the end of the month that that date falls into, then add one calendar month.

Example:

```
Enter jan 13: jan 13 end of month is Jan 31, + 1 month is Feb 28 (or 9 on leap year).

Feb 19: = March 31

March 2 = 30 April

March 30 = 30 April

March 31 = 30 April
```

etc etc

Is there an excel formula that will do this? I don't want any macro/ VBA stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have 2007 or later than:

```
=EOMONTH("3/30/2016",1)
```

Comment: Yep! Working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the Date function, add one to the month and set the Day to zero.  This gives the last day of the month.  To get the last day of the next month add two to the month.

```
=DATE(YEAR(E3),MONTH(E3)+1,0)
=DATE(YEAR(E3),MONTH(E3)+2,0)
```

Comment: Good solution, but Scott's solution worked better *for me*. Other users may find your code suits them better.